# Listview not updating databsase with Dropdown list values

Tags: sql, asp.net, listview, dropdownlistfor

When I  edit items in a Listview from a Dropdown list and press the standard update button the data is not updating.

This is the structure of my database.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Assets] 
         ( 
                      [AssetID] [INT] IDENTITY(20000,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                      [Asset]     NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
                      [Symbol]    NVARCHAR(20) NULL, 
                      [AssetType] NVARCHAR(20) CONSTRAINT chk_asttype CHECK (assettype IN ('Currencies',
                                                                                           'Indices',
                                                                                           'Stocks',
                                                                                           'Commodities')) NOT NULL,CREATE TABLE[dbo].[times] 
                      ( 
                                   timeid [INT] IDENTITY(20010,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
                                   timevalues NVARCHAR (15) DEFAULT '15 Minutes' NOT NULL
                      )CREATE TABLE [dbo].[results] 
                      ( 
                                   [resultid] [INT] IDENTITY(20016,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                                   [result] [NVARCHAR](10)CONSTRAINT chk_result CHECK (result IN ('Won', 
                                                                                                  'Lost',
                                                                                                  'Draw',
                                                                                                  'Prepare',
                                                                                                  'New Signal'))
                      )CREATE TABLE [dbo].[binarysignals] 
                      ( 
                                   [signalid] [INT] IDENTITY(30000,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                                   [assetid] [INT]CONSTRAINT fk_binastid FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES assets(assetid) NOT NULL,
                                   [signaldate][DATE] DEFAULT Getdate() NOT NULL, 
                                   [direction][VARCHAR](4) CONSTRAINT chk_bindirection CHECK (direction IN ('Call', 
                                                                                                            'Put')) DEFAULT NULL,
                                   [strikeprice] [SMALLMONEY] DEFAULT NULL, 
                                   [expiryprice] [SMALLMONEY] DEFAULT NULL, 
                                   [starttime][SMALLDATETIME] DEFAULT NULL, 
                                   [expirytime][NVARCHAR](20) DEFAULT NULL, 
                                   [resultid] [INT]CONSTRAINT fk_binresid FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES results(resultid) DEFAULT 20016 NOT NULL,
                                   [lastupdatedtime][SMALLDATETIME] DEFAULT Getdate() NOT NULL, 
                      )
```

And here is my ASP.Net markup code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {
        ShowTime();
    });
    function ShowTime() {
        var dt = new Date();
        document.getElementById("lblTime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleTimeString();
        window.setTimeout("ShowTime()", 1000);
    }

<div>
        <label id="lblTime" style="font-weight: bold"></label>
        <br />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="BO" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$                  ConnectionStrings:Signals2UConnectionString %>"
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [BinarySignals] WHERE [SignalID] = @SignalID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [BinarySignals] ([AssetID]) VALUES (@AssetID)" SelectCommand="SELECT [SignalID], BinarySignals.AssetID ,[Asset], [SignalDate], [Direction], [StrikePrice], [ExpiryPrice], [StartTime], [ExpiryTime], [Result],Results.ResultID FROM [BinarySignals] 
INNER JOIN  Assets On BinarySignals.AssetID=Assets.AssetID
INNER JOIN  Results On BinarySignals.ResultID=Results.ResultID
ORDER BY BinarySignals.AssetID DESC"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [BinarySignals] SET [AssetID] = @AssetID, [SignalDate] = @SignalDate, [Direction] = @Direction, [StrikePrice] = @StrikePrice, [ExpiryPrice] = @ExpiryPrice, [StartTime] = @StartTime, [ExpiryTime] = @ExpiryTime, [ResultID] = @ResultID WHERE [SignalID] = @SignalID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="SignalID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="AssetID" Type="Int32" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="AssetID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="SignalDate" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Direction" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="StrikePrice" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ExpiryPrice" Type="Decimal" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="StartTime" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ExpiryTime" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ResultID" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="SignalID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Results" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Signals2UConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Result], [ResultID] FROM [Results]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="BO" GroupItemCount="3" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">
            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <td id="Td1" runat="server" style="">SignalID:
                <asp:Label ID="SignalIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SignalID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Asset:
                <asp:Label ID="AssetLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Asset") %>' />
                    <br />
                    SignalDate:
                <asp:Label ID="SignalDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SignalDate","{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Direction:
                <asp:Label ID="DirectionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Direction") %>' />
                    <br />
                    StrikePrice:
                <asp:Label ID="StrikePriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StrikePrice") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ExpiryPrice:
                <asp:Label ID="ExpiryPriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ExpiryPrice") %>' />
                    <br />
                    StartTime:
                <asp:Label ID="StartTimeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StartTime") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ExpiryTime:
                <asp:Label ID="ExpiryTimeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ExpiryTime") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Result:
                <asp:Label ID="ResultLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Result") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ResultID:
                <asp:Label ID="ResultIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ResultID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="">SignalID:

                Asset:
              <asp:TextBox ID="AssetTextBox" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# Bind("Asset") %>' />


                    <br />
                    SignalDate:
                <asp:TextBox ID="SignalDateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SignalDate") %>' />

                    <br />
                    Direction:
                <asp:TextBox ID="DirectionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Direction") %>' />
                    <br />
                    StrikePrice:
                <asp:TextBox ID="StrikePriceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StrikePrice") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ExpiryPrice:
                <asp:TextBox ID="ExpiryPriceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ExpiryPrice") %>' />
                    <br />
                    StartTime:
                <asp:TextBox ID="StartTimeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StartTime") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ExpiryTime:
                <asp:TextBox ID="ExpiryTimeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ExpiryTime") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Result:
               <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" DataSourceID="Outcome" DataTextField="Result" DataValueField="ResultID" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("ResultID") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />

                    <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <EmptyItemTemplate>
                <td id="Td3" runat="server" />
            </EmptyItemTemplate>
            <GroupTemplate>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                    <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>
                </tr>
            </GroupTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <td id="Td4" runat="server" style="">Asset:
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="Assets" DataTextField="Asset" DataValueField="AssetID" AutoPostBack="True" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("AssetID") %>'>
</asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    SignalDate:
                <asp:Label ID="SignalDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SignalDate") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Direction:
                <asp:TextBox ID="DirectionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Direction") %>' />
                    <br />
                    StrikePrice:
                <asp:TextBox ID="StrikePriceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StrikePrice") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ExpiryPrice:
                <asp:TextBox ID="ExpiryPriceTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ExpiryPrice") %>' />
                    <br />
                    StartTime:
                <asp:TextBox ID="StartTimeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StartTime") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ExpiryTime:
                <asp:TextBox ID="ExpiryTimeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ExpiryTime") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Result:
                <asp:TextBox ID="ResultTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Result") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <td id="Td5" runat="server" style="">SignalID:
                <asp:Label ID="SignalIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SignalID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Asset:
                <asp:Label ID="AssetLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Asset") %>' />
                    <br />
                    SignalDate:
               <asp:Label ID="SignalDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SignalDate","{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Direction:
                <asp:Label ID="DirectionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Direction") %>' />
                    <br />
                    StrikePrice:
                <asp:Label ID="StrikePriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StrikePrice") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ExpiryPrice:
                <asp:Label ID="ExpiryPriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ExpiryPrice") %>' />
                    <br />
                    StartTime:
                <asp:Label ID="StartTimeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StartTime") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ExpiryTime:
                <asp:Label ID="ExpiryTimeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ExpiryTime") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Result:
                <asp:Label ID="ResultLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Result") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ResultID:
                <asp:Label ID="ResultIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ResultID") %>' />

                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="Table2" runat="server">
                    <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                        <td id="Td6" runat="server">
                            <table id="groupPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                                <tr id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="Tr2" runat="server">
                        <td id="Td7" runat="server" style=""></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <td id="Td8" runat="server" style="">SignalID:
                <asp:Label ID="SignalIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SignalID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    AssetID:
                <asp:Label ID="AssetIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AssetID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Asset:
                <asp:Label ID="AssetLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Asset") %>' />
                    <br />
                    SignalDate:
                <asp:Label ID="SignalDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SignalDate","{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Direction:
                <asp:Label ID="DirectionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Direction") %>' />
                    <br />
                    StrikePrice:
                <asp:Label ID="StrikePriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StrikePrice") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ExpiryPrice:
                <asp:Label ID="ExpiryPriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ExpiryPrice") %>' />
                    <br />
                    StartTime:
                <asp:Label ID="StartTimeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SignalDate") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ExpiryTime:
                <asp:Label ID="ExpiryTimeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ExpiryTime") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Result:
                <asp:Label ID="ResultLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Result") %>' />
                    <br />
                    ResultID:
                <asp:Label ID="ResultIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ResultID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    <br />
                </td>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Assets" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Signals2UConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [AssetID], [Asset], [AssetType], [Symbol] FROM [Assets]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="times" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Signals2UConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [TimeID], [TimeValues] FROM [Times]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Outcome" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$     ConnectionStrings:Signals2UConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT   [ResultID], [Result] FROM [Results]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

I try to update the Results value which is a Foreign key stored in the Binary Signals table coming from the Results table. Result field is used as the display text and the ResultId as the value for the dropdown list

Comment: Please someone assist. I just need to be able to make the update work on the Result dropdown

Comment: Please anyone assist i have searched the web and still find no solution. I am desperate

Comment: Solved. <asp:Label ID="SignalIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SignalID") %>' /> was missing in teh EditItemTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The below was missing from the EditItemTemplate

```
  <asp:Label ID="SignalIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SignalID")%>'/>
```